# Visual Studio 2017 cross-platform Linux project with boost

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to ask how to include boost hpp files in cross platform Linux project. I am developing on Windows and compiling remotely on Linux with VS 2017.

For IntelliSense the C++ header files from Linux are automatically copied to Windows machine.

1. Is it the case with boost hpp files also? 
       How is it in a case when boost is just extracted from a package on Linux and not installed by apt-get... command?
2. Do I need to install boost on Windows also?
3. How to refer to hpp files so that both VS IDE and g++ would find the files?

Thanks.

Comment: I would consider using CMake or another build system for such a task.

Answer (score 2):

I have to figure out how to make it work, so I post it here if someone else needs a help:

1. To make IntelliSense work, the boost has to be on Windows. The VS can not be instructed to download additional include files from Linux. What it downloads from Linux is not user configurable in VS 2017, so we have to install or download boost files on Windows manually.
2. Add the path to VS in Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.  For example $(ProjectDir)../../boost_1_68_0/;
3. Add path to boost which is on Linux machine. For example: /usr/local/boost_1_68_0/;
4. Now you should be able to compile VS solution and IntelliSense should work.

If someone knows how to avoid installation of boost on Windows and use only boost installation on Linux, please let me know. I don't understand why VS does not allow to manually specify additional includes for a download.